# $b_k = O(1)$, $A_N := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=-N}^N b_k$ converges if $A_{[2^{\epsilon}m]}$ converges for all $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

This is a lemma used to prove a.e convergence of $\sum_{k=-N}^N a^k e^{ikt}$ in my class note:

> Denote $A_N := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=-N}^N b_k$. Suppose $b_k = O(1)$. If $A_{[2^{\epsilon}m]}$ ($[x]$ = largest integer s.t. $\leq x$) converges for all $\epsilon > 0$ as $m \to \infty$, then we could conclude $A_N$ converges as $N \to \infty$.

I think first we could see $A_{[2^{\epsilon}m]}$ have the same limit for each $\epsilon > 0$: I compare $\epsilon < 1$ case to $\epsilon = 1$ case. For large $m$, if $\epsilon < 1$, we could always find some $n$ such that $2^m \leq 2^{\epsilon n} < 2^{m+1}$. So by taking $n,m$ large, and use triangular inequality we see the limits are the same.

But I don't know how to conclude $A_N$ also converges to this limit; I even don't know how to start. Could anyone give me some hint on this?